# Javascript Pointer Events - Wacom Pen Pressure and Tilt not registering

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge, wacom

I am trying to implement the new Pointer Events model using IE Edge, jQuery, the Pointer Events Polyfill (jQuery PEP), and my Wacom Intuos Pro 5 Medium Tablet (drivers are installed and working). The pen events always registers 0.5 for pressure, 0 for tiltX, and 0 for tiltY. What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/skibulk/5avcz377/4/

```
$('#pointerTarget').on('pointerdown pointerup pointermove pointerover pointerout pointerenter pointerleave', 
    function pointerHandler(event)
    {
        $('#pressure span').html(event.originalEvent.pressure);
        $('#tiltX span').html(event.originalEvent.tiltX);
        $('#tiltY span').html(event.originalEvent.tiltY);
    }
);
```

Update: It works with my Wacom Cintiq 22HD Touch! Can anybody try this with their Intuos tablet to narrow the problem down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had somebody else test this using their Wacom Intuos Pro 5 Medium Tablet and it worked fine. So I guess my drivers were corrupt. The funny thing is that they operated normally in Adobe Photoshop...